# How to switch color/material of an object post render? (in EEVEE)

Tags: compositing-nodes

I just rendered out a bunch of frames (for a video) and then realized two objects have the wrong colors on them

If you look at the picture, what I'm pretty much trying to do is make the cube orange and the sphere blue, and with the compositor

I know it can be done in the compositor (from what I gathered in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDXTMo31QSM&ab_channel=DanielKrafft)

but I cant find a decent tutorial on how to do it (I know the video I just mentioned kind of shows you how to do it, but its only for cycles? so idk if i should follow this video, also its drowned in other content that's not exactly relevant to what I'm trying to do)[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You need to output a cryptomat pass or a diffuse pass before and use those as a mask, so basically, you might need to render again and fix it, another option could be rotoscoping the object.

Comment: I don't think there's any way that doing some workaround to "fix" the colors in the composite will be easier and better looking that just fixing the colors in the material and re-rendering. Especially since it's only EEVEE, it can't take that long.